# How to create additional row within a column

Tags: html, css

I have created a row, within my header.php file, that has been split into 5 columns.  I want to 'group' the first 2 columns together with the remaining 3 columns also 'grouped' together.

```
<div class="row">
  <div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="first-column">Text One</div>    //First Column
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="first-column">Text Two</div>    //First Column
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="second-column">Text Three</div> //Second Column
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="second-column">Text Four</div>  //Second Column
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="second-column">Text Five</div>  //Second Column 
  </div>
</div>
```

I have 'grouped' the texts together by entering the following in my css file:

```
#first-column{
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
}
#second-column{
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

As a way to 'separate' the 2 columns, I have used css to apply a different colour to each column.  Now, I would like to apply a column title to the second column but not the first column.

Does anyone know of how best to approach this?  I have followed a few tutorials but it has not achieved the exact goal I am looking for.

I feel it is one of those 'ease when you know how' tasks, so hopefully it will be straight forward.

Comment: put a heading tag in `#second-column`?

Comment: your `DOM` is invalid, you can't use the same `id` more then once on a page, you should convert these to a `class`

Comment: [Is this the result](https://jsfiddle.net/rycx88xm/) you are looking for? btw, id's are supposed to be unique on the whole page, use classes instead.

Comment: split the row in two col-sm-6. and change sm-3 to sm-6 and sm-2 to sm-4

Comment: Michel Coker: I tried your suggestion but the title is restricted to the appointed column rather than appearing across the entire 'grouped' second column. cmorrisey: Thanks for your insight.  I shall amend accordingly. :-) GCyrillus:  Yes, I am using Bootstrap.  pol: Not quite the result but thanks for your input.  Nicolò Cozzani: Are you able to provide a code sample as not 100% sure what you mean.  I tried to apply your suggestion but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve my issue.  For anybody who may have had a similar issue, I have placed the code below.  Just bear in mind that I am using Bootstrap for the column layout and Font Awesome for my icons:

```
<div class="row">                   //This Row Spans full width of page.
    <div class="col-md-8">          //I wanted my row to be split into 2 'parent' columns.  This is the left hand 'parent' column.
        <p>Column Title<p>
            <div class="col-md-4">  //This is the left hand 'child' column within the above parent column.
                Bullet Point 1
            </div>              
            <div class="col-md-4">  //This is the right hand 'child' column within the above 'parent' column.
                Bullet Point 2
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">          //This is the right hand 'parent' column.
        <p>Customer Area:</p>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i>Basket</p>  //This is the left hand 'child' column.
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">  
            <p><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Account</p>  //This is the centre 'child' column.
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>Search</p>  //This is the right hand 'child' column.
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

If anyone sees a compatibility issue, or indeed any other issues with my code, do feel free to let me know. :-)  Hope this helps anyone, who is asking a similar question to me.

Answer (score 0):

why not?

```
<div class="row">
  <div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 first-column">Text One</div>    //First Column
  <div class="col-sm-3 first-column">Text Two</div>    //First Column
  <div class="col-sm-2 second-column">Text Three</div> //Second Column
  <div class="col-sm-2 second-column">Text Four</div>  //Second Column
  <div class="col-sm-2 second-column">Text Five</div>  //Second Column 
  </div>
</div>

.first-column{
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
}

.second-column{
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

IDs mostly appear single

Comment: Thanks Levi.  Changing ID's to Classes was also mentioned in the Comments above.  I have amended accordingly.  Not sure if you are aware but members are able to vote up/down answers and comments etc.  A vote up gains you points while a vote down will cost you points.  If you come across a question, where you require further insight, utilise the Comment section until you are able to provide a full answer.  Don't want to come across as unappreciative of your time and input but thought I would let you know so that you do not lose points in future posts! :-)